# Java 11 Filename validation to prevent OS command injection

Tags: java, validation, command, java-11, coverity

I am trying to resolve coverity issue 'OS _Command_injection'.

filename is read from user uploaded multipart file as below

```
                    String filename = item.getName();
                    String regex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$";
                    if(filename.matches(regex)) {                           
                        
                        if(filename.contains("../") || filename.contains("..") || filename.contains("./") || filename.contains("/")) {
                            throw new BRException("Invalid filename");
                        }
                        Path filePath = Paths.get(location, filename);
                        try ( OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath.toString()); ) {
                            IOUtils.copy(stream, out);                              
                            params.put("filename", filename);
                            params.put("filePath", filePath);
                        }
                    } else {
                        
                        throw new FSException("filename is Invalid");
                    }
```

'subsequent call to invoke shell script using 'filename' complains about OS command injection,                       **this filePath is passed to shellscript which invokes malware scan tool on the file to check for viruses** below is scanFile method accepting filepath

**EDITED**

```
                    scanScriptPath = /scantool/scan.sh; // resolves to path of shell sript

                    StringBuilder scriptNfile = new StringBuilder("").append(scanScriptPath.toString()).append(" ").append(filePath.toString());

                    String[] cmd = {"sh","-c",scriptNfile.toString() };

                                        
                    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);    // OS_Command_Sink              
                    Process proc = pb.start();
                    proc.waitFor();
```

Coverity error message:**OS Command Injection (OS_CMD_INJECTION)7. os_cmd_sink: Calling scanFile. Passing the tainted value filename to the process-invoking API may allow an attacker to modify the intention of the command. (The virtual call resolves to com.xyz.scanFile(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)**

regex validation of filename and checking if filename has path traversal characters is not resolving issue.
what else am i missing?

Comment: First, how are the two code snippets related by control flow?  They both declare `filePath`, which does not make much sense if they are consecutive.  Second, why is it *running* `filePath` as a shell command?  Is this application allowing the user to upload and run an arbitrary shell script?  That would of course be unsafe.  Third, it would help to see the exact Coverity message, either by carefully copying and formatting its text or including a screenshot.

Comment: @ScottMcPeak user uploaded file is scanned for malware, scan tool is invoked using shellscript, i have updated coverity error message

Comment: There is no “shellscript which invokes malware scan tool” in what you’ve posted. All there is, is an attempt to run the file path as shell command, as Scott McPeak already said. There is no way to solve this issue with some validation, as the whole thing you’re doing *is* the problem.

Comment: @Holger i have updated code in question - command passed to processBuilder contains path to shellscript and path of file to scanned.

Comment: That’s an unnecessarily complicated way to get the same as `scanScriptPath + " " + filePath` but why was this update even necessary? Obviously, because the code in your question is not the actual code your question is about. That’s not helpful. Besides that, the audit tool might not even have the knowledge to decide whether a pattern validation is sufficient. The simplest solution is to store the file under a predefined name first, scan it under that name, then rename it to the user specified name.